# Mantis bug tracker - Send mail while adding notes

Tags: mantis

While adding notes to an existing mantis bug tracker issue, i would also like to add a few email ids to which the note could be mailed to.

Is this scenario possible ? And has any one used any hacks to do the same.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are u admin in ur mantis system ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding those people/addresses as observers(? Beobachter in german) is my workaround. Not an option for you?